# Get distinct values from the values of a certain column with some formatting

Tags: postgresql, split

I have a table in pgadmin (old verion pgadmin3) of the following format. Please note the commas at the beginning and the end of the values

my_table

[id column_name
1   , val1,
2   , val1, val2,
3   , val2, val4, val5,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6PT4.png)

| id | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | , val1, |
| 2 | , val1, val2, |
| 3 | , val2, val4, val5, |

I would like to get the following output

expected outcome

[new_id column_name
1   val1
2   val2
3   val4
4   val5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imqCK.png)

| new_id | column_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | val1 |
| 2 | val2 |
| 3 | val4 |
| 3 | val5 |

So basically I want the output to be of distinct values.

I have been trying a different scripts with no success. (Please again note the commas at the beginning and at the end of the strings in that column. They need to be removed too in the process)

Can you please help me on this.

Thank you,

Shaun

Answer (score 1):

First normalize the data by splitting `my_column` into rows (this is the `t` CTE) and then select distinct values. `trim` function is used twice to clean the commas and spaces from the list string.

```sql
with t as
(
  select id, l.list_item 
  from my_table m
  cross join lateral 
  (
    select trim(s) as list_item  
    from unnest(string_to_array(trim(m.column_name, ', '), ',')) s
  ) l
) 
select distinct on (list_item) id, list_item as column_name 
from t 
order by list_item, id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Split the string and discard the empty strings. Then, for each value, take the lowest matching `id`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (c.c)
       m.id, c.c
FROM mytab AS m
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL regexp_split_to_table(m.column_name, ', *') AS c(c)
WHERE c.c <> ''
ORDER BY c.c, m.id;

 id |  c   
----+------
  1 | val1
  2 | val2
  3 | val4
  3 | val5
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response. In this code what do you declare by c.c? and how is it different to c(c).

Comment: `c(c)` is an alias for the table function: "a table `c` with a column `c`". `c.c` references this column. You can choose different names like `parts(column_part)` if that makes the query clearer to you.

Comment: it definitely is Laurenz. Thank you very much! seems like a lot to learn. Is there a good resource to learn Postgres SQL? on line?

Comment: I recommend the online documentation. Comprehensive, to the point and correct. That's how I learned PostgreSQL.